# Host a web site in an Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-machine

I have a Azure VM. Using the IIS, I host a website in the VM.

How can I access that website via the DNS name (like http://abc.cloudapp.net/)
I know this is the most unlikely, we should use the "web role", but I really need this works, is this possible?

I tried with the localhost, it works, the internal IP works, but the DNS name doesn't.

Edited to provide more info (March 09):
I have already have endpoints setup. "binding" uses the dns name. I have two website, one hosted in the port 8081, it works. Another one hosted in the port 80, which doesn't work.

http endpoints
[image]

the port 80 doesn't work
[image]

the port 8081 works
[image]

Comment: "_I know this is the most unlikely, we should use the "web role"_ " - there is no rule stating you should use a web role; hosting a website in VM+IIS is perfectly valid, with its own set of advantages/disadvantages.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your VM already has a Azure domain in the form of `myvmname.cloudapp.net` right?

First you need to add an **ENDPOINT** in the VM that bridges the port 80 from outsite to inside (if that is the port indeed you configured in IIS).

[image]

Then, you need to add a **CNAME record** in your DNS table that points from `www.mydomain.ext` to `myvmname.cloudapp.net` (obviously replacing the correct values).

Comment: thanks for your reply, I am still confused, I created a new VM, do the same, then it works, without any CNAME record, any advice please?

Comment: You only need a CNAME record if you want your Custom Domain to work, the default `cloudapp.net` domain should work without this step. If the VM was created by some Azure Marketplace offering, maybe that particular offering adds the EndPoints automatically, check the EndPoints in your Settings.

Comment: thanks for your reply Matias, I edited my question to provide more info:Edited to provide more info (March 09): I have already have endpoints setup. "binding" uses the dns name. I have two websites, one hosted in the port 8081, it works. Another one hosted in the port 80, which doesn't work.

Comment: the port 80 with dns name even doesn't work inside the VM

Comment: If you swap ports? does the now-80-before-8081 app work? If it does, it's an intrinsic problem of the App. Are you getting a 404? 500?